# What is the caster level of a summoned creature with the Greenbound template?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, druid, summoning, character-templates, caster-level

The Greenbound template gives your summoned creatures the ability to cast spell-like abilities, at will, with the description:

> Caster level equals greenbound creature's character level; save DC 10 + spell level + greenbound creature's Charisma modifier.

Now, Greenbound gives the +8 to Level adjustment. Some templates have no level adjustment. Others have a few here and there.

So, help a noobie out, what is the resultant "level" of your summons through Summon Nature's Ally, if only for knowing the caster level in this case?

Comment: Welcome to rpg.se! Take the [tour] and visit the [help] for more information. For future reference the best way to show the system you are playing is by including the appropriate system tag. (e.g. [tag:dnd-3.5e]). Thanks for contributing and happy gaming!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Character level is equivalent to hit dice. Level adjustment only applies to “effective character level,” and that only matters for XP and leveling up. Every other effect will not include level adjustment. So it’s just the creature’s HD.